# JavaScript: Take first three characters of each word in string and put "_" after each word

Tags: javascript

> What I would like to achieve is take a string:

```
var string = "Hello there my friend";
```

> And return a formatted string as follows:

```
"HEL_THE_MY_FRI"
```

So I am trying to take the first three characters of each word in a string and add an underscore after each. The capitalize is easy :) .toUpperCase()

Comment: `my` word doesn't  contain three characters, why it was also followed by `_` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I think the explanation doesn't take edge cases into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `replace` for that:

```js
var string = "Hello there my friend";

var result = string.toUpperCase().replace(/\b(\S{1,3})\S*/g, '$1').replace(/ /g, '_');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide any code for what you've tried so far, the steps you'd take are:

- split the string on spaces
- loop over your array of words
- get a substring from each word 3 characters long
- uppercase the substring
- append it to your new string
- add an underscore if it isn't the last word in your array

```js
var phrase = 'this is my string';
var words = phrase.split(' ');

var result = '';
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  var word = words[i];
  result += word.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
  
  if (i < words.length - 1) {
    result += '_';
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: LoL. You should have provided the code by Mahi! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't like doing someone else's homework for them if they're not even willing to show what they've tried.

Comment: Your code snipit looks similar to what I was doing, I was just seeing how others world go about doing it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Man, I was so sarcastic. Coz both yours and his answers should be combined. It was like a coincidence.

Comment: @Clusi you should still add your code attempt to your question. That's why it's getting downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("Hello there my friend".split(" ").map((a)=>a.substring(0, 3)).join("_").toUpperCase());
```

Comment: LoL. You should have provided the explanation by Soviut! `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar merge both answer :P

Answer (score 0):

*"One-line"* solution using `String.replace()`, `String.toUpperCase()` and `String.slice()` functions:

```js
var string = "Hello there my friend",
    replaced = string.replace(/\b(\w{1,3})(\w+\s?|\s)/g, '$1_').toUpperCase().slice(0,-1);
    
console.log(replaced);
```